# Could my boyfriend be hiding his encrypted emails inside of my inbox?

Tags: network, http, exploit

is it possible that my boyfriend could be hiding his encrypted emails inside of my email inbox with my email address and I can't read them? And if it if that is possible is there way that I can decrypt and read them?

Comment: if this is not the correct place for me to post is question instead of voting me out could somebody please direct me in the right place to post is question I appreciate it thank you

Comment: To clarify...have you found emails that are encrypted that you want to read or do you suspect there are such emails but cannot see them in your email client?

Comment: Yes, I can copy and paste my emails to you if you like, it's just a bunch of strange dots and what looks like locations and their inside of my emails that I'm sure are only covers for whatever these messages truly are, which I suspect arey boyfriend's hidden messages that he's hiding right under my nose and making me feel crazy for even thinking such a thing could be possible...

Comment: I think that you should have a look at [interpersonal.se] and perhaps see if there is a way to improve the trust relationship to your significant other. Because judging from what I have read so far, your relationship with your boyfriend doesn't seem...healthy.

Answer (score 4):

Hiding emails in your inbox would not be a smart move. Email accounts are free, so there's no need to use another account to store them.

Any email that is stored on your account should be visible to you. Even if those emails are stashed on another folder (not on inbox, for example). You can access all folders and see if there's something suspicious. If you find something suspicious *and* encrypted, you probably won't be able to decrypt without the key.

If you suspect anyone is using your email account, change the password immediately. This is an easy way to lock anyone out.

But I don't think your boyfriend would be using your account to hide emails from you. Does not make sense.